# Как добавить в корзину товары с Wildberries с помощью requests или хотя бы сформировать fetch запрос

Tags: python, парсер, requests, curl, fetch

Всем привет, возникла проблема при добавлении товаров в корзину wildberries. Ссылка для post запроса формируется локально и имеет вид

> https://a.wb.ru/e/ec?t=Wildberries%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wildberries.ru%2F&cid=4&s=1920x1080x24&w=1536x553&user_id=44173961705307831&vbn=325&timestamp=2024-01-16T05%3A33%3A19.249Z&timezone_offset=180&timezone=Europe%2FMoscow&client_id=w7TDssOkw7PCu8KwwrHCscKzwrDCtcKzwrDCtA%3D%3D&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wildberries.ru%2Flk%2Fbasket

вот curl запроса

> curl
> "https://a.wb.ru/e/ec?t=Wildberries^%^20^%^E2^%^80^%^93^%^20^%^D0^%^98^%^D0^%^BD^%^D1^%^82^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^80^%^D0^%^BD^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^82-^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^B0^%^D0^%^B3^%^D0^%^B0^%^D0^%^B7^%^D0^%^B8^%^D0^%^BD^%^20^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B4^%^D0^%^BD^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B9^%^20^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B4^%^D0^%^B5^%^D0^%^B6^%^D0^%^B4^%^D1^%^8B^%^20^%^D0^%^B8^%^20^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B1^%^D1^%^83^%^D0^%^B2^%^D0^%^B8&u=https^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fwww.wildberries.ru^%^2F&cid=4&s=1920x1080x24&w=1536x553&user_id=6473834454676&vbn=325&timestamp=2024-01-16T05^%^3A33^%^3A19.249Z&timezone_offset=180&timezone=Europe^%^2FMoscow&client_id=uhefuwhefiwefsokfosjefwj^%^3D^%^3D&r=https^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fwww.wildberries.ru^%^2Flk^%^2Fbasket"
> -X POST -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0" -H "Accept: */*" -H
> "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" -H
> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H
> "Origin: https://www.wildberries.ru" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H
> "Referer: [https://www.wildberries.ru/"](https://www.wildberries.ru/%22) -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" -H
> "Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors" -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site" --data-raw
> "{""action"":{""type"":""add_to_cart"",""currency"":""RUB""},""products"":^[{""utcTime"":""2024-01-16 08:33:19"",""id"":""179834964"",""nm"":173456788,""chrt"":29732321,""name"":""^Н^а^с^т^о^л^ь^н^а^я
> ^и^г^р^а ^д^л^я ^к^о^м^п^а^н^и^и
> ^Б^у^л^л^и^н^г"",""brand"":""GAME_HUB"",""price"":436,""inListIndex"":1,""listName"":""MCS^|CR^|popular^|^|^|^|^|"",""variant"":""^ч^е^р^н^ы^й"",""quantity"":1,""affiliation"":""625305^|507"",""category"":""regular"",""category2"":""120"",""category3"":""7"",""coupon"":""1123^|4.8""}^],""cp"":{""country"":""ru"",""cluster"":""10""}}"

Я пытался сформировать ее локально, но видимо неверно формировал, а WB на все запросы возвращает 200 то есть даже не проверить без залезания в корзину.

Вот js код который вроде формирует ссылку:

```html
!function () {
    "use strict"; function t(t, e) { var n = {}; for (var i in t) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, i) && e.indexOf(i) < 0 && (n[i
        ] = t[i
        ]); if (null != t && "function" == typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) { var o = 0; for (i = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(t); o < i.length; o++)e.indexOf(i[o
            ]) < 0 && Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(t, i[o
            ]) && (n[i[o
                ]
            ] = t[i[o
                ]
            ])
        } return n
    } var e = "_wbauid", n = "user_id", i = "goal_reach"; (new (function () { function o() { this._ecCurrency = "", this._ecProductItems = null, this._debugMode = !1
        } return o.prototype.init = function () { var t = this; this.initTime = window.wba.l, window[
                "wba-url"
            ] = "https://a.wb.ru/e"; var e = window.wba.q; Array.isArray(e) && e.forEach((function (e) { t.HandleCmd(e[
                    0
                ], e[
                    1
                ])
            })), window.wba = this.HandleCmd.bind(this)
        }, o.prototype.initUserId = function (t) { var e = this.getUserID(); ("" === e || t) && (e = this.genNewUserID(), this.isNewUser = !0), this.userId = e
        }, o.prototype.getUserID = function () { return document.cookie.split(";").map((function (t) { return t.trim()
            })).filter((function (t) { return "_wbauid=" === t.substring(0, e.length + 1)
            })).map((function (t) { return t.substring(e.length + 1)
            }))[
                0
            ] || ""
        }, o.prototype.HandleCmd = function (t, e) {
            null == e && (e = {}); try { switch (t) { case "init": this.HandleInitCmd(e); break; case n: this.HandleSetClientIdCmd(e); break; case i: this.HandleGoalReachCmd(e); break; case "ec:send": this.ECHandleSendCmd(e); break; case "ec:addProduct": this.ECHandleAddProductCmd(e); break; case "ec:setCurrency": this.ECHandleSetCurrencyCmd(e); break; case "ec:setAction": this.ECHandleSetActionCmd(e); break; case "ec:clear": this.ECClear(); break; default: this.HandleSimpleEvent(t, e)
                }
            } catch (e) { try { this.isDebugMode() && console.error("An error occurred while handling '" + t + "' command:\n\t" + e)
                } catch (t) {}
            }
        }, o.prototype.genNewUserID = function () { var t = Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1e3), e = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2,
            30)).toString() + t.toString(), n = new Date; return n.setTime(n.getTime() + 31536e6), document.cookie = "_wbauid=" + e + "; expires=" + n.toUTCString() + "; path=/; domain=" + this._cookieDomain, e
        }, o.prototype.HandleSimpleEvent = function (t, e) { this.SendEvent(t, this.BuildStatParams(),
            { cp: e
            })
        }, o.prototype.ECClear = function () { this._ecAction = null, this._ecProductItems = null
        }, o.prototype.ECPrepareJSON = function () { var t = {}; return null == this._ecAction ? t.action = { type: "unspecified", currency: this._ecCurrency
            } : t.action = this._ecAction,
            null != this._ecProductItems && (t.products = this._ecProductItems), t
        }, o.prototype.ECHandleAddProductCmd = function (t) {
            null == this._ecProductItems && (this._ecProductItems = []),
            null == t.inListIndex && null != t.position && (t.inListIndex = t.position, delete t.position),
            null != t.list && (null == t.listID && (t.listID = t.list),
            null == t.listName && (t.listName = t.list), delete t.list), this._ecProductItems.push(t)
        }, o.prototype.ECHandleSendCmd = function (t) { var e = this.ECPrepareJSON(); e.cp = t, this.ECClear(), this.SendEvent("ec", this.BuildStatParams(), e)
        }, o.prototype.ECHandleSetCurrencyCmd = function (t) { this._ecCurrency = t,
            null != this._ecAction && (this._ecAction.currency = t)
        }, o.prototype.ECHandleSetActionCmd = function (t) {
            "object" == typeof t ? this._ecAction = t : (null == this._ecAction && (this._ecAction = {}), this._ecAction.type = t), this._ecAction.currency = this._ecCurrency
        }, o.prototype.HandleSetClientIdCmd = function (e) { var i = e.clientId, o = t(e,
            [
                "clientId"
            ]); this.clientId = i, this.SendEvent(n, this.BuildStatParams(),
            { cp: o
            })
        }, o.prototype.HandleInitCmd = function (t) { this.counterId = t.counterId, this.clientId = t.clientId, this._debugMode = !0 === t.debugMode; var e = t.cookieDomain; "string" == typeof e && 0 !== e.length ? this._cookieDomain = e : this._cookieDomain = window.location.hostname; var n = t.resetUserId; if (this.initUserId("boolean" == typeof n && n), this._debugMode) try { console.log("Initialization done:\n\tthis.counterId='" + this.counterId + "'\n\tthis.userId='" + this.userId + "'\n\tthis.clientId='" + this.clientId + "'\n\tthis._debugMode='" + this._debugMode + "'\n\tthis._cookieDomain='" + this._cookieDomain + "'\n\tSDKVersionBuildNum='325'")
            } catch (t) {}
        }, o.prototype.HandleGoalReachCmd = function (e) { var n = e.name, o = e.price100, r = e.currency, c = t(e,
            [
                "name",
                "price100",
                "currency"
            ]), s = this.BuildStatParams(); s.gn = n, s.gp100 = o, s.gcr = r, this.SendEvent(i, s,
            { cp: c
            })
        }, o.prototype.BuildStatParams = function () { var t = {}; t.t = document.title.substring(0,
            500), t.u = document.URL, t.cid = this.counterId, t.s = this.GetScreenInfo(), t.w = this.GetWindowInfo(), t.user_id = this.userId, t.vbn = "325"; var e = new Date; t.timestamp = e.toISOString(), t.timezone_offset = -e.getTimezoneOffset(), t.timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone, this.clientId && (t.client_id = this.clientId); var n = document.referrer.trim(); return n.length > 0 && (t.r = n), this.isNewUser && (t.nu = 1), t
        }, o.prototype.GetScreenInfo = function () { return (0 | window.screen.width * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1)) + "x" + (0 | window.screen.height * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1)) + "x" + (0 | window.screen.colorDepth)
        }, o.prototype.GetWindowInfo = function () { return (0 | (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth)) + "x" + (0 | (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight))
        }, o.prototype.SendEvent = function (t, e, n) { void 0 === n && (n = {}); var i = []; Object.keys(e).forEach((function (t) { var n = e[t
                ]; null != n && i.push(encodeURIComponent(t) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(n))
            })); var o = i.join("&"), r = window[
                "wba-url"
            ] + "/" + encodeURIComponent(t) + "?" + o, c = JSON.stringify(n); this.sendData(r, c)
        }, o.prototype.sendAsXHR = function (t, e) { var n = new XMLHttpRequest; n.open("POST", t), n.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
            "text/plain"), n.send(e)
        }, o.prototype.sendAsBeacon = function (t, e) { var n = new window.Blob([e
            ],
            { type: "text/plain"
            }); try { if (window.navigator.sendBeacon(t, n)) return
            } catch (t) {} this.sendAsXHR(t, e)
        }, o.prototype.sendData = function (t, e) { window && window.navigator && "function" == typeof window.navigator.sendBeacon && "function" == typeof window.Blob ? this.sendAsBeacon(t, e) : this.sendAsXHR(t, e)
        }, o.prototype.isDebugMode = function () { if (this._debugMode) return !0; try { return window.location.href.indexOf("_adebug=1") >= 0
            } catch (t) { return !1
            }
        }, o
    }())).init()
}();
```

Очень нужна помощь в написании кода добавления в корзину

Comment: что такое `цшдвиуккшуычерез`?

Comment: Wildberries, раскладку забыл сменить, сори

Comment: Дружище, решился вопрос? Тоже интересно сделать тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

requests.post(
    "https://a.wb.ru/e/ec?t=Wildberries^%^20^%^E2^%^80^%^93^%^20^%^D0^%^98^%^D0^%^BD^%^D1^%^82^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^80^%^D0^%^BD^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^82-^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^B0^%^D0^%^B3^%^D0^%^B0^%^D0^%^B7^%^D0^%^B8^%^D0^%^BD^%^20^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B4^%^D0^%^BD^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B9^%^20^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B4^%^D0^%^B5^%^D0^%^B6^%^D0^%^B4^%^D1^%^8B^%^20^%^D0^%^B8^%^20^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B1^%^D1^%^83^%^D0^%^B2^%^D0^%^B8&u=https^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fwww.wildberries.ru^%^2F&cid=4&s=1920x1080x24&w=1536x553&user_id=6473834454676&vbn=325&timestamp=2024-01-16T05^%^3A33^%^3A19.249Z&timezone_offset=180&timezone=Europe^%^2FMoscow&client_id=uhefuwhefiwefsokfosjefwj^%^3D^%^3D&r=https^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fwww.wildberries.ru^%^2Flk^%^2Fbasket",
    headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0",
    "Accept":"/",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "Origin": "https://www.wildberries.ru",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://www.wildberries.ru/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "no-cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site"
    },
    data={"action":{"type":"add_to_cart","currency":"RUB"},"products":[{"utcTime":"2024-01-16 08:33:19","id":"179834964","nm":173456788,"chrt":29732321,"name":"^Н^а^с^т^о^л^ь^н^а^я ^и^г^р^а ^д^л^я ^к^о^м^п^а^н^и^и ^Б^у^л^л^и^н^г","brand":"GAME_HUB","price":436,"inListIndex":1,"listName":"MCS^|CR^|popular^|^|^|^|^|","variant":"^ч^е^р^н^ы^й","quantity":1,"affiliation":"625305^|507","category":"regular","category2":"120","category3":"7","coupon":"1123^|4.8"}],"cp":{"country":"ru","cluster":"10"}}
)
```

Comment: Видишь ссылка уникальна? То что он возвращает 200 на значит что товар в корзине. Мне нужно формировать ссылку как это делает сайт (внутри себя с помощью js)

Comment: Тогда для этого нужен не requests, который только работает с запросами, а нужно использовать эмуляцию браузера (К примеру selenium)

Comment: Ну я про это и написал, что мне нужен либо fetch либо что то еще для полной эмуляции запросов